# How to add nano.uuid to the chain of promises that read from the DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, pouchdb

I am using this code with express routing and nano:

```
router.get('/', function (request, response) {
  db.view('designdoc', 'bydate', { 'descending': true })
    .then(results => {
      // data manipulation of results, all blocking and fine
      return results;
    })
    .then(results => {
        nano.uuids(1)
          .then(uuids => {
            results.uuid = uiids['uuids'][0];
            resolve(); // return ?
          })
          .catch(error => {
          // ?
           });
      });
      return results;
    })
    .then(results => { response.json(results); }) // how to have results.uuid = something from the previous then ?
    .catch(error => { response.json(error); });
```

I want to add an uuid from `nano.uuid` to the results but I can't figure out how to manipulate the promise inside the next `then`.

How can I fetch the data from `nano.uuid`, wait for it and add it to `results` ?

## edit

I am switching to the async approach suggested by @narayansharma91 and this code solves my problem:

```js
    router.get('/', async function (request, response) {
      const results = await db.view('designdoc', 'bydate', { 'descending': true });
      var uuid = await nano.uuids(1);
      results.uuid = uuid.uuids[0];
      response.json(results);
    }
```

But I still would like to understand a solution based on promises.

Comment: Performance tip: there is no a reason to run `await db.view` and `await nano.uuids` one after another, you can use `Promise.all` to get better response time: `const [results, uuid] = await Promise.all([db.view('designdoc', 'bydate', { 'descending': true }),  nano.uuids()])`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this long script to get the result. You can do the same thing using `async/await` like below.

```
 router.get('/', async function (request, response) {
     const result = await db.view('designdoc', 'bydate', { 'descending': true })
     console.log(result)//do what ever you want to with result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function successcb(results){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    nano.uuids(1)
  .then(uuids => {
    results.uuid = uiids['uuids'][0];
    resolve(results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    throw err;
   });
  });
}

router.get('/', function (request, response) {
  db.view('designdoc', 'bydate', { 'descending': true })
    .then(results => {

      return results;
    })
    .then(successcb)
    .then(results => { response.json(results); }) 
    .catch(error => { response.json(error); });
```

Comment: @Mohit Sahu Something's off. With the debugger I can see results gets the uuid property but the final the response sent in the final then doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't changed much from your code because you wanted a solution in promises. You don't need to call resolve() because .then() does that for you. After attaching uuids to result, just return the results.

```
router.get('/', function (request, response) {
    db.view('designdoc', 'bydate', {
            'descending': true
        })
        .then(results => {
            // data manipulation of results, all blocking and fine
            return results;
        })
        .then(results => {
            results = nano.uuids(1)
                .then(uuids => {
                    results.uuid = uiids['uuids'][0];
                    return results;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    throw error;
                });
            return results;
        }).then(results => {
            response.json(results);
        }) // how to have results.uuid = something from the previous then ?
        .catch(error => {
            response.json(error);
        });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/', function(request, response) {
            let _results;
            db.view('designdoc', 'bydate', {
                    'descending': true
                })
                .then(results => {
                    // data manipulation of results, all blocking and fine
                    // save results in tempopary variable
                    // since we want to use only one level of Promise chains
                    // we need to save results on controller scope level to allow access in further chains
                    _results = results;
                    // we don't need to return since every `then` by default return `Promise`
                })
                .then(() => {
                    // you can just return, since nano.uuids return Promise
                    // next then chain will be called once action completed
                    return nano.uuids();
                })
                .then(uuids => {
                    // use _results from controller level scope
                    // uuids will be injected as a result of return nano.uuids()
                    _results.uuid = uiids['uuids'][0];
                    response.json(_results);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    response.json(error);
                });
        }
```

For better understanding of `Promise` chain I'm always suggest to read this [great article](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)